# How to detect is there audio output to speakers

Tags: java, windows, audio, system

I need a way to detect if there is any audio pass to speakers from any program on Windows.

Basically I need to know if there is sound on the speakers on some remote PC where my program is running. If I go to control panel->sounds on playback tab, I can see green bar showing output level from that audio device. Is there any way to read that value; or just is it 0 or something else?